# how to give id with f.country_select in carmen gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carmen

Hi I am using `gem 'carmen-rails'`
In my view I have written this

```
<%= f.country_select :country, prompt: 'Please select a country',
                                   :id=>'curr-country' %>
```

but its not taking this id 'curr-country'. Please guide how to give id in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: <%= f.country_select :country, { prompt: 'Please select a country',
                                   id: 'curr-country'} %>

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to pass a second hash with the HTML options:

```
<%= f.country_select :country, 
                    { prompt: 'Please select a country' },
                    { id: 'curr-country' } %>
```

The `carmen-rails` gem doesn't document this explicitly (it is documented [in code](https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails/blob/50ebda9ac696306abdfc6ebd75af06cd79de2ded/lib/carmen/rails/action_view/form_helper.rb#L54)). The `country_select` gem, however, does provide an example of this in the [Usage section of the `README`](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#usage)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= f.country_select :country, {id: 'curr-country', prompt: 'Please select a country'} %>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= f.country_select :country, {priority: %w(US CA)}, {prompt: 'Please select a country'}, {:id => 'your-id'} %>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Why you added the `{priority: %w(US CA)}` part ? OP didn't mention anything like that.........

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.country_select :country, {},  class: "form-control" %>
```

Try this one :)